# Get Link for url by clicking on chart label

Tags: jquery, django

I need to create link for `URL` in `djano` dynamically when user clicks on particular label on chart
like when user click in chart on column on 26/06/2018 `URL` should be like 26/06/2018/get_data/.
I am using jquery.

```
$("#chart-1").on('click', function (test,key){ //chart ID   
    var label = $('#test');  //div containing data in json
    var text = jQuery.parseJSON(label.text());
    jQuery.each(text, function(i, val) {
    var array  = []
    jQuery.each(val,function(key,label){
        $('rect').addClass('myclass');
        var index = label['label'].indexOf('Undefined');
        if (index !== -1) label['label'].splice(index, 1);
        array.push(label['label']);
        var url = "{% url 'log:get_data'%}";
        var id = array[1];
        var url2 = (id  + url);
        console.log(url2) 
        document.location.href = url2;
    });
});
```

[Including image for the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EITPu.png)

[image]

Comment: what's the problem/question?

Comment: At present I am getting url statically by mentioning which value from array i need .Ideally i need it need be generated dynamically by array value which user clicks